# Apple's own instructions on how to make horizontally scrollable UIScrollView with Auto-layout do not work?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am trying to make simple `UIScrollView` containing single "Content View" and scrolling horizontally only. It should be fairly easy given there are [step-by-step instructions from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithScrollViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH24-SW1). Only, it does not seem to work - the `UIScrollView` still scrolls both directions.

Here is screenshot of complete view hierarchy with all constants. Selected is the constant that should (according to 6. in Apple's docs linked above) prevent vertical scrolling.

[image]

Here is screenshot from device proving that the "Content View" can still be scrolled vertically. I set background color of the scroll view to white, background of the "Content View" to black and a view that contains scorllview (top-most container) is light grey. Because you can see white strip over black "Content View" you can also scroll black "Content View" up.

[image]

Is there something I am missing? If not is there a workaround?

Comment: are you setting the height of the scrollview to 280 or of the contentView? the content view within a scroll view must have a defined height and width, not set relative to the size of the scroll view. any constraints describing the relation of the content view to the scroll view will not be used to calculate width/height

Comment: i was mobile earlier, else i would have also posted this link: http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/ idk if the examples specifically work there, but just reading through that article helped me to understand this topic

Comment: Could downvoter please explain himself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the view controller is set to automatically inset the scroll view. This setting is useful if the scroll view sits behind a navigation bar but is sometimes problematic. In the storyboard check the setting on the view controller and remove it.

Comment: Perfect guess. You were right, it fixed the problem. Thank you for help sir!